# Question about decreasing malloc size by using realloc

Tags: c

I am trying to decrease the size of a malloc array, but it is throwing -1073741819 (0xC0000005) when I realloc a smaller size for the malloc.

```
typedef struct {
    float reproduce_prob;
    int mature;
    int life;
    int age;
    char *direction;
    int X;
    int Y;
} slug;
slug *slugs = (slug *) malloc(sizeof(slug) * (slugCount + 1));
int slugCount = 0;
                        if (slugCheck(theGrid, frogs[i])) {
                            int pos = feedFrog(frogs[i], slugs, slugCount);
                            for (int z = pos; z < slugCount - 1; z++) {
                                slugs[z] = slugs[z + 1];
                            }
                            slugCount--;
                            slugs = realloc(slugs, sizeof(slugs) * (slugCount + 1));
                            frogs[i].initHung = 0;
                        }
```

the slugCount is not zero.

Comment: (1) Please provide the full program (where do you `malloc` the `slugs`?, where do you init the `slugCount`?) (2) "Throwing" `0xC0000005`? If it is returning `0xC0000005`, that would seem like a reasonable address to me. You should only worry about `realloc` returning `NULL`.

Comment: The initial code is a bit large, and the debugger stopped at realloc line.

Comment: @LMD FWIW `0xC0000005` doesn't seem like a reasonable address for `realloc` to return: it's not aligned to a word boundary. We don't know what a `slug` is, but `realloc` doesn't know what the caller is going to store, so has to make the most pessimistic assumption possible about alignment.

Comment: @bzs: You're allocating something to `sizeof(slugs) * ...`. The variable `slugs` is a pointer, so probably only 8 bytes, which may be smaller than the actual structure you want to store. Presumably you meant `sizeof(slug)`?

Comment: 0xC0000005 it is an access violation error in Microsoft

Comment: I have not allocated anything to slugs after decreasing it's size, that why I am confused.

Comment: As psmears notes, `foo = realloc(…, sizeof foo…)` is generally an error. It should be `foo = realloc(…, sizeof *foo…)` to allocate space for the type `foo` points to, not for the type `foo` is. Or, in this case, you can use `sizeof (slugs)` instead of `sizeof *slug`, since `slugs` is the name of the type that `slug` points to. However, it is often recommend to use `sizeof *foo` because that automatically adjusts in case the type of `foo` is ever changed.

Answer (score 2):

It is good practice to use obects not types in the `sizeof`s. Also it is good to have **distinct** and meaningful type and variable names to avoid this kind mistakes. I would call `slug` `slugType` or `slug_type`.

in this line you do not allocate enough space (assuming that the slug structure is larger than the pointer) as sizeof(slugs) is giving the size of the pointer to `slug`:

```
slugs = realloc(slugs, sizeof(slugs) * (slugCount + 1));
```

You also incorrectly use realloc as realloc may fail and you will have memory leak

```
slug *tmp;
tmp = realloc(slugs, sizeof(*tmp) * (slugCount + 1));
if(tmp)
{
    slugs = tmp;
}
else
{
    /* error handling */
}
```

As a side note: do not cast the result of `malloc` family functions. If Your code does not compile it means that you use C++ compiler to compile the C language code. It is not a good idea as C & C++ are different languages even if syntax looks similar.

Comment: Is it because the direction is char* which might increase in size depending on what is inside?

Comment: @BZS no it is not.

Answer (score 2):

How does this code compile?

```
slug *slugs = (slug *) malloc(sizeof(slug) * (slugCount + 1));
int slugCount = 0;
```

The compiler should be yelling at you for using `slugCount` *before* it has been defined.

If this code is building it means you’ve already defined `slugCount` in an enclosing scope, and its value may not be zero.  That’s one problem.

You should *always* check the result of `malloc`, `calloc`, and `realloc`.  Are you certain that neither the `malloc` nor `realloc` call have returned `NULL`?

This line is suspicious:

```
slugs = realloc(slugs, sizeof(slugs) * (slugCount + 1));
```

`sizeof(slugs)` gives you the size of the *pointer*, not the `slug` type - you haven’t extended your array by one element, you’ve shrunk it by a whole helluva lot.  You might want to change that to

```
slug *tmp = realloc( slugs, sizeof *slugs * (slugCount + 1) );
```

You should always assign the result of `realloc` to a temporary variable.  `realloc` will return `NULL` if it can’t satisfy the request *and leave the original buffer in place*.  However, if you assign that `NULL` result back to your original pointer, you will lose your only reference to that memory.